# What is this icon in Wizard101?

Tags: wizard101

I have [searched](http://www.wizard101central.com/wiki/Category:Icons) the wizard101 icon list but can't seem to find a match to what this icon means:

[image]

I'm sure it's some sort of defense attribute, but I can't figure out which one. Thoughts?

Comment: Opaque defense opal gives +17 to resistance and global, it looks like this is a messed up version of both of them combined. It's like the global icon tried to load and half failed.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud interesting, that's good to know